# Find a string on a CSV file and print that line on a HTML Table

Tags: php, html, wordpress, csv

I have a Wordpress website where I use a PHP plugin to show data from a CSV file. I'm using this code that I have found on our forum that convert the CSV data on a HTML table, it's really usefull:

```
<?php
    echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
    $f = fopen("file.csv", "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
            $row = $line[0];
            $cells = explode(";",$row);
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

I have found this code `$title = get_the_title( get_option('page_for_posts', true) );` to get the page title and I want to print the first line of the CSV (header) and use the title variable to find the name on the first column of the CSV and print only these two lines of the CSV on HTML table format.

Thanks you.

Comment: Perhaps it might be helpful if you shared some of the csv data

Comment: I can't tell what the purpose of `$row = $line[0]; $cells = explode(";",$row);` is supposed to be here - `fgetcsv` should already read one full line into an array of individual column values.

Comment: $row = $line[0]; $cells = explode(";",$row);

This code format the table to put every data on a cell without ";" separations. The result is a clean table. I didn't wrote the code but it works fine.